# My Angular code using Observables seems to be making an extra (unwanted) HTTP request

Tags: angular, rxjs, frontend, observable, single-page-application

Apologies in advance for the length - it's not a complicated issue; I'm just trying to be as explicit as possible. Also be forewarned: I'm new to Angular and building SPA's in general. There may be a fundamental misunderstanding here.

My app is basically a "ToDo" app at this point. It gets a list of "Issues" from an api endpoint and outputs them to a list. Next to the list is another list of Issue categories that can be clicked to sort the Issue list by category id. Individual issues can also be clicked to open a single Issue view.

My **Issue Service** GETS all issues and all Issue categories from the api endpoint:

```js
// GET all Issues
getIssues(): Observable<Issue[]> {

  return this.http.get<Issue[]>(this.issuesUrl);
}

// GET all Issue Categories
getIssueCats(): void {

  return this.http.get<IssueCategory[]>(this.issuesCatUrl);
}
```

My **Issue List Component html** outputs the Issues and Issue categories to lists using an async pipe. The categories can be clicked to run a catSort() method and update the url parameters with /?category=[CategoryName]:

```html
<h2>Categories:</h2>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let issueCat of (issueCats$ | async)">
        <a routerLink="/" [queryParams]="{ category: issueCat.name }">
            {{ issueCat.name }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<h2>Issues:</h2>
<div>
    <a *ngFor="let issue of (issues$ | async)" routerLink="/issue/{{ issue.id }}">
        {{ issue.title.rendered }}
    </a>
</div>
```

My **Issue List Component** runs getIssueCats() and getIssues() methods in it's ngOnInit() life cycle hook. All of my Issue categories are stored in an issueCats$ variable and output to the template. All of the Issues themselves are stored in a allIssues$ variable as well as piped to an issues$ variable which is output to the template. Loading this component results in two http requests - one each to the Categories and Issues endpoints:

```js
export class IssueListComponent implements OnInit {

  allIssues$: Observable<Issue[]>;
  issueCats$: Observable<IssueCategory[]>;
  issues$: Observable<Issue[]>;

  category: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private issueService: IssueService
    )
  {
    route.queryParamMap
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.category = params.get('category');
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getIssueCats();
    this.getIssues();
  }

  getIssues(): void {

    this.allIssues$ = this.issueService.getIssues().pipe(map(data=>data), share());
    this.issues$ = this.allIssues$.pipe(map(data=>data));
  }

  getIssueCats(): void {

    this.issueCats$ = this.issueService.getIssueCats().pipe(map(data=>data));
  }

  catSort(): void {

    // note: 5 is hard-coded for testing
    this.issues$ = this.allIssues$.pipe(map(data=>data.filter(issue => issue.cat === 5)));
  }
}
```

**The problem:** when I click a category my app sends an additional HTTP GET request to Issues every time it is clicked (as per network tab of the Firefox Developer dev tools). Since I already have all my Issues at that point I would just like to "shuffle" the existing ones and update the url to reflect the category being shown.

I would also like to use a similar functionality to load single Issue views, i.e. sorting my list of all Issues by a single Issue unique id and passing that Issue to the view.

If anyone can steer me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Every time you subscribe to an observable the sequence repeats, this means http observables rerun. You need to use caching methods or publish operators to make sure they only execute when you actually want them to

Comment: Sounds like you probably want some form of the replay operator. If you ever want to update the list you will need to introduce a trigger into the stream to do that. Here is a good resource for understanding the different operators you may want to pick from: https://medium.com/@_achou/rxswift-share-vs-replay-vs-sharereplay-bea99ac42168